# How to retrieve data from firebase database array on react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database that has a child with 3 other child. Like

Database:
 section1:
     Imageurl:
          0:data1
          1:data2
          2:data3

how can I retrieve data from image URL as a whole and  one by one[image]

Comment: did you use react-redux-firebase ? or simple firebase web.. and did you have the childrenkey of flyers that you want to fetch (674cafe2.....)?

Comment: @HazimAli I Use simple firebase web. I don't have children key of a flyer